# Python - creating list with lists from for loop

Tags: python

New to python and I´m trying to create a list from the lists created on for loop:

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[8,5,6]]
for l in range(len(A)):
    resultado = []
    A2 = A[l][::-1]
    resultado.append(A2)
    print(resultado)
```

The current output is:

```
[[3, 2, 1]]
[[2, 3, 4]]
[[6, 5, 8]]
```

I´m trying to make this:

```
 [[3, 2, 1],[2, 3, 4],[6, 5, 8]]
```

Comment: as you can see the needed result can be easily obtained with one line of code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[x[::-1] for x in A]
# [[3, 2, 1], [2, 3, 4], [6, 5, 8]]
```

---

You can also `reverse` the list in place:

```
for x in A: 
    x.reverse()

A
# [[3, 2, 1], [2, 3, 4], [6, 5, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension would work as well:

```
resultado = [l[::-1] for l in A]
```

Answer (score 0):

Then use this following code

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[8,5,6]]
B=[]
for l in range(len(A)):
    A2 = A[l][::-1]
    B.append(A2)
print(B)
```

Answer :  `[[3, 2, 1],[2, 3, 4],[6, 5, 8]]`

Answer (score 0):

Adjust like below:

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[8,5,6]]
resultado = []

for l in range(len(A)):
    A2 = A[l][::-1]
    resultado.append(A2)

print(resultado)
```

`resultado = []` inside your `for` loop, means for each iteration, you initialize `resultado` to `[]`

**Output:**

```
>>> print(resultado)
[[3, 2, 1], [2, 3, 4], [6, 5, 8]]
```

**Note:** You can achieve the same result with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
>>> [list(reversed(item)) for item in A]
[[3, 2, 1], [2, 3, 4], [6, 5, 8]]
```